# Is HTML5 drag and drop compatible with Chrome Apps (packaged)?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I've tried the traditional methods and it works as a webpage in Chrome, but not when I'm using the page as a packaged app.

I'm just doing this example from W3 for testing purposes since it's very simple.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: What have you already tried? Are you receiving any particular errors?

Comment: It wasn't responding at all to drag and drop, I just found the solution and posted it as an answer below. It's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by utilizing the -webkit-user-drag CSS property on the element (in my case an image). This allowed the dragging in the app window itself.

```
img {
-webkit-user-drag: auto;
}
```

I then put event listeners for all the other javascript functions (inline javascript not allowed in Chrome Apps) that can be seen at the w3 link in the description.

Now the drag and drop acts like it does on a regular webpage.

Answer (score 0):

this is not supported in Chrome Android, see in caniuse: http://caniuse.com/#search=drag

Comment: I'm not using the Chrome Android version, I'm using a Packaged Chrome App, which is on the desktop.

Comment: Then it should work as it runs in the desktop version of Chrome.

Comment: Packaged Chrome Apps are web apps but are "Google proprietary" to a degree. Which is why I'm specifically asking about compatibility.